# Image not showing In LaTex

Tags: graphics, size, wide-image

I'm new to LaTex, so I apologize in advance if it's dumb question.

I have two images (grafs) that I want to add to my document.

The first one i used this code and it's working:

```
\begin{landscape}
\includegraphics[width=20cm]{Grafo1.png}
\end{landscape}
```

The second one is a bit larger, so when I use the same code nothing shows. I've reduced the size, done scalling, but still got the problem.

Does anyone knows how I can fix this?

The image I want to add is 11228 x 413

My Code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small, %o tamanho das fontes que são usadas para o código
    numbers=left, % onde colocar a numeração da linha
    numberstyle=\tiny, %o tamanho das fontes que são usadas para a numeração da linha
    numbersep=5pt, %distancia entre a numeração da linha e o codigo
    breaklines=true, %define quebra automática de linha
    frame=tB,  % caixa a volta do codigo
    mathescape=true, %habilita o modo matemático
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)} % se escrever isto  aceita tudo o que esta dentro das marcas e nao altera
}

\usepackage[portuges]{babel} % Babel
% vai ativar automaticamente as regras apropriadas de hifenização para a língua portuguesa; todo o texto gerado é automaticamente traduzido para Português
% por exemplo, "chapter" vai passar a "capítulo", "table of contents” a “conteúdo”
% "portuges" específica para o Português

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % define o encoding usado texto fonte (input)
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx} % permite incluir gráficos, tabelas, figuras
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

\title{Relatório Ontologia Desportos Marítimos com Prancha}
\author{Nuno Ferreira }
\date{Março 2021}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{LogoUM.jpg}\vfill
Paradigmas de Progamação II
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{flushright}

Docentes:\par
Pedro Henriques\par
Cristiana Araújo\par
\vfill

Trabalho elaborado por:\par
Nuno Ferreira\par
Mestrado de Ensino Informática\par
PG44268

\end{flushright}

\newpage


\section*{Introdução} \label{sec:Introducao}
Este relatório é referente à ontologia de desportos do mar com prancha, com principal foco no hobby escolhido por mim: Bodyboard. 
No entanto, e dado que o próprio tema poderia ser redutor, serão abordados ainda que de forma superficial, outros desportos com a mesma característica. A saber: Windsurf, KiteSurf e Surf, sendo que do último tema, é o que detenho mais algum conhecimento, até pela interação que há entre os praticantes das modalidades quando juntos no mar.\par

Como já referido anteriormente a ontologia incide sobre o Bodyboard, sendo que para a prática do mesmo é necessária uma prancha, cujo tamanho terá que ser adequado à altura do atleta. No mercado existem várias opções de marcas e de tamanhos. 
Para além da prancha, é também necessário o equipamento conhecimento como pés de pato, que irá permitir ao praticante “apanhar” a onde. Esse equipamento deve ser adquirido conforme o número do pé do atleta. \par

Há um elemento que não é considerado para a ontologia, pela sua imprevisibilidade: condições meteorológicas. A prática de qualquer um desses desportos depende impreterivelmente do estado do mar e do vento. Em certos locais, a corrente marítima ou ausência de vento pode favorecer a prática do bodyboard e do surf, e prejudicar o kitesurf e windsurf. O vento ao sentir-se com mais intensidade, privilegia a prática do kitesurf e do windsurf, prejudicando a do bodyboard e surf. Deste modo, as condições meteorológicas não foram tidas em conta, dado que é um fator que o atleta não possui controlo sobre as mesmas. \par

Para essa ontologia foi considerado um conceito de atleta que pode praticar apenas uma modalidade, sendo que a que é dada mais enfase é o bodyboard, ou então várias. Desse modo ele pode ter várias pranchas, de várias marcas e vários tamanhos, bem como das várias modalidades.\par

\newpage
\section*{Ontologia Desportos Marítimos com Prancha} \label{sec:OntoDLBB}
A Listagem 1 exibe (numa linguagem formal, OntoDL) a descrição de uma Ontologia no domínio dos DesportoMarPrancha.\par
\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
Esta ontologia possui como classes: \emph{bodyboard, surf, kitesurf, windsurf, desportoPrancha, desportoPranchaAsa, desportoPranchaVela, pranchaBodyBoard, pranchaSurf, pranchaWindSurf, pranchaKiteSurf, AsaKiteSurf, VelaWindSurf, pesPato, manobrasBodyboard, manobrasSurf, atleta. }\par
\vspace{5mm} %5mm vertical space
Possui três relações não taxonómicas (não hierárquicas) \emph{tem, pratica e faz}.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Descrição da Ontologia “DesportoMarPrancha”}, label={Listagem 1}]

Ontologia DesportoMarPrancha

conceitos { bodyboard, surf, kitesurf, windsurf, desportoPrancha, desportoPranchaAsa, desportoPranchaVela, 
    pranchaBodyBoard [marca:string , tamanho:string, tipo:string], 
    pranchaSurf [marca:string, tamanho: string],
    pranchaWindSurf [marca:string, tamanho: string],
    pranchaKiteSurf [marca:string, tamanho: string],
    AsaKiteSurf [marca: string, tamanho: string],
    VelaWindSurf [marca:string, tamanho:string],
    pesPato [marca:string, tamanho:string],
    manobrasBodyboard [nome: string],
    manobrasSurf [nome:string],
    atleta [nome : string]      
}

relacoes{ tem , pratica, faz
}

triplos {

    bodyboard =is-a=> desportoPrancha;
    surf =is-a=> desportoPrancha;
    kitesurf =is-a=> desportoPranchaAsa;
    windsurf =is-a=> desportoPranchaVela;

    atleta =pratica=> desportoPrancha;
    atleta =pratica=> desportoPranchaAsa;
    atleta =pratica=> desportoPranchaVela;
    
    
    
    atleta =tem=> pranchaBodyBoard;
    atleta =tem=> pesPato;
    
    atleta=tem=> pranchaSurf;
    atleta=tem=> pranchaKiteSurf;
    atleta=tem=> pranchaWindSurf;
    atleta=tem=> AsaKiteSurf;
    atleta=tem=> VelaWindSurf;
    
    atleta =faz=> manobrasBodyboard;
    atleta =faz=> manobrasSurf
    
}.
    
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{5mm} %5mm espaço vertical
Após processar a descrição da ontologia exibida na Listagem 1 no processador ontoDLProcessor obteve-se a Ontologia “DesportoMarPrancha” em formato DOT (ver Listagem 2).

\begin{lstlisting} [caption={Ontologia “DesportoMarPrancha” em formato DOT”}, label={Listagem 2}]

\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{5mm} %5mm espaço vertical
Com recurso à ferramenta web Edotor gerou-se o grafo da Ontologia “DesportoMarPrancha”.

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\section*{Grafo da Ontologia} \label{sec:Grafo}
\includegraphics[width=20cm]{Grafo1.png}
\end{landscape}

\newpage
\section*{Ontologia Desportos Marítimos com Prancha – Instanciada} \label{sec:OntoDLBB-Inst}

Foram acrescentadas algumas instâncias à Ontologia “Desportos Marítimos com Prancha”,
sendo elas:
atleta1, atleta2, atleta3, atleta4, atleta5, pranchaBB1, pranchaBB2, pranchaBB3, pranchaBB4,
pranchaBB5, pranchaBB6, pranchaS1, pranchaS2, pranchaS3, pranchaKS1, pranchaWS1, asa1,
vela1, manobraBB1, manobraBB2, manobraBB3, manobraBB4, manobraBB5, manobraS1,
manobraS2, manobraS3, pespato1, pespato2, pespato3, pespato4, pespato5.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Descrição da Ontologia “Desportos Marítimos com Prancha” com instâncias”}, label={Listagem 3}]


    
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{5mm} %5mm espaço vertical
Processou-se a descrição da ontologia, através do processador ontoDLProcessor e obteve-se a seguinte Ontologia, com instâncias em formato DOT (ver Listagem 4).

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Ontologia “Desportos Marítimos com Pranchas” com instâncias em formato DOT}, label={Listagem 4}]


    
\end{lstlisting}

\vspace{5mm} %5mm espaço vertical

Novamente com recurso à ferramenta web Edotor gerou-se o grafo da Ontologia “Desportos Marítimos com Pranchas”, com as suas instâncias.
\includepdf[pages=-]{GrafoFinal.pdf}

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\section*{Grafo da Ontologia - Instanciado} \label{sec:Grafo_insta}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{GrafoFinal.png}

\end{landscape}
\newpage


\end{document}
```

I have the FinalGrafo image in a png file and also in a PDF file. I have tried both ways, and the result is the same: it doesn't show.

Comment: Do you not get any error messages? If you are wrapping your images in floats (e.g. figure) they might move to somewhere else in your document where you would not expect them to (I've had floats move over a hundred pages due to other graphs, images and tables).

Comment: No, i'm not using nothing like that. I'm very new to Latex.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message. Regarding the first image I do get something like: Overfull \box (19.0511pt too wide) in paragraph.....

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly is going wrong without having some code to work with. One thought is that because you're using them with "landscape" then width essentially becomes height. Maybe that's what's messing with you here.

Comment: What code do you want me to post here that might be hepfull?

Comment: If possible a minimal tex file from \documentclass{} to \end{document} including any packages that you are using to get those images to do what you want them to do and how you call the images in the document.

Comment: And how do I upload this file?

Comment: The Images are called Grafo1.png and GrafoFinal.png. I'm using Overleaf. The picture Grafo1, is showing correctly with the code that I have above. When I use it with the GrafoFinal.png that by the way is 112228 x 413, I don't a get an error message. A blank page is created with nothing to show.

Comment: When you make your example with the question you include the whole code for the document so those who might like to help you can simply copy paste it and work with it (the same way you have included the image code now).

Comment: I've had the code that i'm using. Just deleted the code that is the list

Comment: When I run your code with large images it works fine for me if I set the width to 20cm, even when I've made the second image to the size you specified (11228 x 413). I think the problem is that it's so disproportionally wide that it is very hard to get any kind of proper reading of the image even if you fit it to landscape. I did get an error and had to comment out \usepackage{natbib} to make it work so maybe that does something weird.

Comment: I've only discovered this: the image doesn't show or takes a long time to appear in the Overleaf, however, when I compile the project and export it to PDF it shows... so I guess it was working all the time. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two images by inserting a linebreak after the first image. Then the second image will come under the first image.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\begin{document}    

\begin{landscape}

    \includegraphics[width=20cm]{grafs.png}\\
    \includegraphics[width=20cm]{grafs.png}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The output of the above code is as follows [image]

Also visit my youtube channel [WP Galaxy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy0vz71kvXSJSmrzHGL77Rg) for LaTex Tutorials and subscribe the channel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it didn't work. I think it migth have something to do, with my image being very big: 11228 x 413.

Comment: change the width of the table by writing 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{grafs.png},

Now the image will take the complete width of the page.